# How to calculate this line integral (using Stokes' theorem?)

Tags: integration, parametrization, stokes-theorem

I'm trying to solve this question:

Let $\underline u \colon \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ be a vector field defined as
$$
\underline u(x,y,z) = (x^3+2y+z,\,y^3+2x+z,\,1/2(x^2+y^2)+x+y)\,.
$$
Let $K$ be the curve of intersection of the surfaces $V$ and $S$, where $V: x+y-z=1$ and
$$
S: \begin{cases} z = 1-x^2-y^2\,, \\ z \geq 0\,. \end{cases}
$$

Calculate 
$$
 \int_K \underline u \bullet\underline t \,ds\,,
$$
where $K$ is along the path $(1,0,0)$ to $(0,1,0)$.

---

The answer appears to be
$$
 \int_K \underline u \bullet\underline t \,ds = 0
$$

---

We've been learning Green and Gauss' theorems, as well as Stokes' theorem in class. I figured Stokes theorem is best applicable here, as we don't want to calculate the flux, but rather the work done when moving along this curve.

I first calculated the curl and divergence;
\begin{align*}
\text{div}\underline u &= 3x^2 + 3y^2 \\
\text{curl}\underline u &= (y,-x,0)
\end{align*}

We now know, by Stokes' theorem
$$
\iint_S \text{curl} \underline u \bullet \underline n \,d\sigma = \oint_{K'} \underline u \bullet \underline t \,ds\,,
$$
if $K'$ is the complete inclined ellipse (where $K$ is a small part of) and $S$ is the surface of this ellipse.

I have found parametrizations of $K'$ (and $S$), but these are not pretty;
\begin{align*}
 k(t) &= \left(-1/2+\sqrt{5/2}\cos t, -1/2+\sqrt{5/2}\sin t, -2+\sqrt{5/2}(\cos t + \sin t)\right)\,, \\
 s(r,t) &= \left(s\left[-1/2+\sqrt{5/2}\cos t\right], s\left[-1/2+\sqrt{5/2}\sin t\right], -1+s\left[-1+\sqrt{5/2}(\cos t + \sin t)\right]\right)\,,
\end{align*}
where $t \in [0,2\pi]$ and $s \in [0,1]$.

Now I could try to work out this integral:
$$
 \iint_S \text{curl}\underline v \bullet \underline n \,d\sigma = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 \text{curl}(v(s(r,t))\bullet \left( \frac{\partial k}{\partial r} \times \frac{\partial k}{\partial t} \right)\,dr dt\,,
$$
but I don't think thats really doable, plus I would only know the work done for the the full ellipse ($K'$) and not for the small part ($K$).

I was also thinking about the fact that the normal on $S$ is the same for every point. I could use the vector $\underline n = (-1,-1,2)$, and normalize $\underline n' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(-1,-1,2)$, and write
$$
 \iint_S \text{curl}\underline v \bullet \underline n \,d\sigma = \iint_S (y,-x,0)\bullet \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(-1,-1,2) \,d\sigma\,,
$$
yet I would probably still need to use the parametrization.

To tackle the problem directly (without using any of the theorems), I would need to find the start and end points of $k(t)$, which is also difficult by hand.

What is the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: Can you precise what $\bullet$ means? Dot product?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net yes, the dot product

Comment: $K$ is the entire elliptical curve; the last sentence, poorly written though it be, is meant to tell you in which direction $K$ is traversed.

Comment: @TedShifrin S is only defined for z >= 0, right?

Comment: You're doing fine. Can you reason out $\iint_S y\,d\sigma$ and $\iint_S x\,d\sigma$ without any computations? (Think symmetry.)

Comment: Oh, ugh. I hadn't noticed the $z\ge 0$. Then it's not a closed curve, and there's no way to apply the big theorems. You just have to parametrize and calculate along the piece of the ellipse. (So my previous remarks are invalid.) You've already parametrized. You just need to figure out the correct interval for $t$ values.

Comment: By the way, as @RobertZ points out, you got your unit normal wrong. The $2$ shouldn't be there (and if it were, your magnitude would be $\sqrt6$), and — if you were to apply Stokes's Theorem — you need to make sure the normal is pointing in the direction compatible with the orientation on your boundary curve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Use Stokes theorem
$$\oint_{K\cup K'} \underline u \bullet \underline t \,ds=\iint_S \text{curl} \underline u \bullet \underline n \,d\sigma$$
where $S$ is the surface given by the the part of the plane $x+y-z=1$ inside the closed curve $K\cup K'$  where $K'$ is the segment $[0,1]\ni t\to (t,1-t,0)$.
Note that the normal to the plane is $\underline n=(1,1,-1)/\sqrt{3}$.
Hence
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\iint_S (y,-x,0)\bullet (1,1,-1) \,d\sigma
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\iint_S y \,d\sigma-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\iint_S x \,d\sigma=0$$
because $S$ is symmetric with respect to the plane $y=x$.

Finally  the integral along $K'$ is easy to evaluate: 
$$\int_{K'}\underline u \bullet \underline t\, ds
=\int_0^1 [(t^3+2(1-t))\cdot(1)+((1-t)^3+2t)\cdot(-1)]dt=0.$$

Comment: The OP already got this far.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin Ops, I overlooked that. But $n$ is wrong in his answer. Am I right?

Comment: Yeah, you're right that the normal should point upwards (and I don't know where the $2$ came from), since $K$ is traversed counterclockwise. **However**, you and I both missed the condition that $z\ge 0$ on the paraboloid. So there are no closed curves in this problem. :( So Stokes's Theorem is not applicable.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin  Yes, but we can cloese the path with the segment $[0,1]\ni t\to (t,1-t,0)$ .

Comment: True enough. And conveniently the curve $K$ and that segment are both contained in the plane $V$, so you just have to find the flux across a tiny region in $V$ and then adjust by the other line integral. Very clever! I usually taught my students to look for this trick with surfaces, but not with curves :)

Comment: However, how is $\text{curl } \underline u\cdot \underline n = 0$ in $V$? (I would recommend you find a new letter. $S$ is already defined in the problem.)

Comment: Aah I see, however; you want to find a vector orthogonal to the plane inside the curve $K \cup K'$ and not ortogonal to $\text{curl}\underline u$, correct?

Comment: No, you have the right normal. But I don't believe it's orthogonal to $(y,-x,0)$.

Comment: @Dennis van den Berg I edited my answer. It seems to work now isn't it?

Comment: @Dennis van den Berg  Sorry for the mess. That was wrong. See my edited answer.

Comment: @RobertZ I understand, the only part I am missing is; how do you know for sure that the intergral over $\text{curl} \underline u \bullet \underline n = 1/\sqrt{3}(y-x) = 0$?

Comment: Sorry for deleting and reposting my comments; I can't seem to edit them.. (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339725/users-without-the-comment-privilege-unable-to-edit-their-own-comments)

Comment: @RobertZ I see, thank you!